# Uno Platform C# Create Material Card

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-ui, uno-platform

I am using the [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) and trying to create a [Material Card](https://gallery.platform.uno/) through C#. I have been able to find a number of examples of a Card created in XAML but nothing in C#.

My current code is below to create a Card and add it to a Grid. I know I need to do something with adding a HeaderContentTemplate and SubHeaderContentTemplate but I am sure exactly what needs to be done.

```
Card myCard = new Card();
myCard.HeaderContent = "test";
myCard.SubHeaderContent = "test";
Grid.SetRow(myCard, k);
Grid.SetColumn(myCard, l);
myGrid.Children.Add(myCard);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the Material Cards working through C# so I ended up making a template xaml and C# file which I build the structure of my card. Then I created that through C#.

Comment: Consider accepting own answer for future visitors